# Why are the different ways to write a universal statements equivalent?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Consider the following universal statements:

1. $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}, a^2 > 0$
2. $\{a \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}| a^2 > 0 \} = \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$
3. $a\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\} \Rightarrow a^2>0$

Why are the 3 statements equivalent?

Writing them in words:

1. For every element $a$ in the set $\mathbb{R} - {0}$, the statements $a^2>0$ is true.
2. The set where $a^2>0$ is true where $a \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ is equal to the set$\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$.
3. If $a$ is in $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, then $a^2>0$.

Written in words, the 3 statements does sound more or less the same to me but I was wondering is there a rigorous way to show that the 3 statements are equivalent e.g. using truth tables? I what the truth table for the 3rd statement should look like (an implication) but I don't know how to deal with the first two statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the universe is $\mathbb{R-0}$ and the language is $(.,>,0)$, statements 1 and 3 translate to:
$$\forall a(a^2>0)$$
And 3 is the universe that this formula is true on it

Comment: What can we say about statement 2?

Comment: @mauna - 2 is expressed in "set language" and in set theory equality between sets is mutual inclusion. Thus, we have to show that $\mathbb R − \{ 0 \}$ is included into $\{ a ∈ \mathbb R− \{ 0 \} | a^2 > 0 \}$ - which is trivial - and vice versa, which is : for all $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $a \ne 0$ we have $a^2 > 0$.

Comment: you should specify if you speak in first order logic or second order and what is your language and universe.